# how to group several rows into 1 group with a range of values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a data set like this

```
|flt   |OrgiDest|Gt  |
|------|--------|----|
|CX 261| CDG    |1.0 |
|CX 383| ZRH    |2.0 |
|CX 880| LAX    |3.0 |
|CX 105| MEL    |5.0 |
|CX 237| LHR    |5.0 |
```

My ultimate goal is to find out the top 5 occurrence flt in Gt range 3.0 - 5.0, I tried sort by Gt from min to max but dont know what's the next step.

Comment: Can you add expected output? Maybe data should be changed, for simplier sample data is possible use top3?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and get first 5 index values:

```
df.loc[df['Gt'].between(3,5), 'flt'].value_counts().index[:5]
```